# Vim - lookahead and lookbehind together to escape unescaped backslashes

Tags: regex, vim, escaping

In vim find all `\` chars which are not followed by `"` , not followed by `\`
and not preceded by `\` and replace them by `\\`

Input:

```
bla1 \ bla1
bla2\bla2
bla3\\bla3
bla4\"bla4
\bla5
bla6\
```

Output:

```
bla1 \\ bla1
bla2\\bla2
bla3\\bla3
bla4\"bla4
\\bla5
bla6\\
```

Tried combination of negative lookbehind and lookahead but no luck for case 3

```
%s/\\\@<!\\\("\)\@!/\\\\/g
```

If there are already 2 backslashes the third one should not be added 
Is it possible to give the negative lookahead 2 characters instead of one.
In other words tell something like and not followed by A or B

Comment: `find all \ chars which are not followed by " and not proceded by \ and replace them by \\ ` your input/output doesn't fit your requirement.  as you required, `bla3\\bla3` should be changed into `bla3\\\bla3` because the first `\\` should be replaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I've solved it

```
%s/\\\@<!\\["\\]\@!/\\\\/g
```

Explanation:

```
\\\@<!        - not preceded by \
\\            - actual \ character 
["\\]\@!      - not followed by either " or \
/\\\\/g       - replace by \\
```

Comment: Please, "preceded" not "proceded".  The third line of your expanded version can be simplified to `["\\]\@!`:  there is no need to group a single atom unless you plan to use it in a back-reference.  Also, your comment here is correct, unlike the original statement of the problem:  In "\\", one backslash is preceded by another, and one is followed by another, and it seems you do not want to expand either one.

Comment: Another simplification:  use `[\"]` instead of `["\\]` and save one character in the pattern!

Comment: Thanks benjifisher Your first simplification worked, the second produced an error. I've updated the answer and also fixed the typo

Comment: Funny, I tested `[\"]` and did not get an error.  I am using vim 7.3.315; what is your version?

Comment: Hi my one is: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 12 2013 00:23:19) I know that there are different "magic modes" and depend which one you use you have to or not escape some characters

Comment: I know what was the issue you tested `[\"]` while I've tested `["\]` The order was different. Could you try the different order and confirm that this is the case please

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/[^\\]\zs\\\ze[^"\\]/\\\\/g
```

this change your input into your output. and personally I think it is easier to be understand than the look-around.

Comment: I think this fails if "\" is the first or last character of the line.

Comment: yes it fails when the '\' is the first character. Added 2 mre test cases to the original question